# Remote connection from one network to another over raspberry pi

Tags: networking

Apologies in advance if anything is incorrect, I'm still a begginer.

I have two networks, one public with a few smart home devices and one that is private, hosted on an LTE Router.

Is there any way to self-host a remote connection to a computer on the private network from the public network ? It's possible to connect to local devices on both networks and I am able to have a raspberry pi connected to both at the same time, I thought maybe I could somehow forward traffic through it from one network to the other but don't know if that's actually realistic or possible.

Here is a diagram if it's of any help:
[Network Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3EGdB.jpg)

Comment: We need a little more information in your question.  It's no clear if you are trying to link the two networks together or just a specific client.  A diagram and clearer examples of what kind of traffic/access should/shouldn't be allowed would be helpful here.  At any rate, this sounds like you could achieve it by creating a VPN tunnel between the two networks or devices...depending on your actual goals here.

Comment: @spaceman-spiff Thanks, I've added a diagram now. What is and isn't allowed between the networks isn't really important; there aren't any devices that shouldn't be able to access the private network on the public network.

Comment: Then, what is it that actually makes one network "public" and the other "private"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your Raspberry Pi is directly connected to both networks – and if both networks use *different addresses* – you can just think of it as a router, as connecting two networks is exactly what a router does.

1. Enable the "IP forwarding" setting in Linux via sysctl. This basically enables the "router" feature.
2. If the "Public Network's" main router supports defining *static routes*, create one towards the opposite network with the Pi as gateway. (Specifically, the Pi's "*public* network" address – the one that's facing the router you're configuring – is the one that goes in the "gateway" field.)

   If the router does not support that, then the same route would need to be added on your laptop (and would only allow connections from the laptop).
3. Similarly, if the "Private Network's" main router supports defining static routes, also create one towards the public network, again with the Pi as gateway. This lets the *reply* packets from the PC travel back to your laptop.

   If the router doesn't support that... either add the route on the PC, *or* enable SNAT (aka masquerading) in the Pi. Using NAT would allow you to access all devices on the private network, though it's kind of ugly in principle.
4. Finally, use the Pi's firewall rules (iptables 'FORWARD' chain) to decide what can be accessed. In your case, just make sure it allows everything.

Answer (score 0):

One simple way is to use the tool `ncat`. The main answer here goes into it: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/293304/using-netcat-for-port-forwarding

Since you're connecting to 2 networks, I assume your Pi has two network interfaces (e.g. two Ethernet ports or an Ethernet + WiFi). I haven't personally set up ncat that way but it will probably just work, especially if you specify the IP address to listen on as part of the `-l` option.

However, if your two networks use the same subnet (e.g. they're both using 192.168.1.x) then things get harder because the kernel won't automatically know which network you're trying to talk to when you specify an IP address for ncat to forward packets to. In that case, you'll need to use the `ip route` commands to tell the kernel that connections to a certain ip address use a certain interface (e.g. eth0, eth1, wlan0, etc). That's sort of a separate topic but these posts go into it:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/368690/why-netcat-doesnt-use-the-right-interface-associated-with-the-ip

https://serverfault.com/questions/123553/how-to-set-the-preferred-network-interface-in-linux/836708#836708